# My computer is making a buzzing noise

Tags: windows, noise

I have this really annoying high pitched noise that comes from my computer no matter what. It does it while POSTing, while booting, while playing games, even while writing this question! It goes something like that:
dii dee do doo DEE DEE DEE doooo -repeat-

It also makes a different noise while playing games, like when I hover over a button it becomes louder etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the noise a fan or is it an actual noise the motherboard? Does it seem to be coming from anywhere specific when you open the case (video card/hard drive)?

Comment: I can't seem to pinpoint the source but it comes from the CPU area. I couldn't pinpoint it because I have 2 GPUs and a huge CPU cooler and it's not easy to navigate around the mobo.

Comment: Record the noise and share it online.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a "faulty fan" sound, rather a skrilling high pitch sound that goes up and down every now and then. Sounds to me more like a capacitor that is making that noise, or another electronic component chip or transistor. I would simply now blindly assume it could be the power supply of your PC !

> To test this try the below (advanced tech, use caution) :

1.) Remove your PSU completely with all the cables. On your PSU main plug-to-mainboard, contact the green pin and any black pin. Then connect the power supply cable. The FAN of the power supply should now spin up. See if the noise is there.

2.) On cold boot, briefly attempt to stop the FAN's of your machine. Make sure you don't damage any FAN fins and only to keep them "off" for 5 seconds max, so that you can try and identify the location of the noize.

3.) Also check on your mainboard for bulged (round) capacitors. Usually all the caps on teh mainboard should be flat ontop. If they are round or seem to have brown/black liquid coming out then they need to be replaced. Check your mainboard thoroughly...

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of two things, in my humble experience:

1. A faulty hard disk - back up everything immediately, replace HD.
2. A faulty fan - this is easier to replace, and sometimes all it requires is cleaning:

Get a $3 air spray, open the computer/laptop, go to a well aired area (this is important, as cleaning a fan results in a puff of dust), make sure the computer is off, and spray that fan. While there, listen to it and find out if it's the same noise you described. If the fan is still making a noise, just replace it.

Comment: 1. I have an SSD. 2.I've checked every single fan before asking this. It's not a fan.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your assumption of the noise coming from the CPU area, the most likely cause of this would be your CPU cooler or fan running fast or maybe rubbing up against something. As I can't hear the noise, I most likely can't pinpoint it.

Your best bet is to stop the fan (just for a second) and see if the noise stops. If it does then there is your culprit. Otherwise move on and locate the damaged component. Replacing a damaged fan is very cheap and easy.

Comment: I've put my finger in the middle of the fan and well, the noise continued.